# Capped string ladder

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string `s` and a positive integer `N`, gradually duplicate each character more and more until `N` duplicates, and then staying at `N` duplicates until `N` characters away from the end, then step down again.

For example, given `abalone` and `3`:

```
a    we start with 1 copy
bb   then 2 copies
aaa  then 3 copies, which is our second parameter
lll  so we continue using 3 copies
ooo  until we reach the end
nn   where we use 2 copies
e    and then finally 1 copy
```

and the result would be `abbaaalllooonne`.

It is guaranteed that the string has length greater than `2N` and only has characters from `a` to `z`.

More testcases:

```
N string       output
2 aaaaa        aaaaaaaa
3 abcdabcdabcd abbcccdddaaabbbcccdddaaabbbccd
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
JṡFṢị⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r4c6Fbg93Lnq4u/tR447/h5frP2paE/n/fzSXQrR6YlJiTn5eqrqOgnGsDlgABIBcIyg3KTkFhsGKuGIB)

#### How it works

```
JṡFṢị⁸  Main link. Arguments: s (string), n (integer)

J       Get the indices of s.
 ṡ      Split the indices into overlapping chunks of length n.
  F     Flatten the array of chunks.
   Ṣ    Sort the resulting array of indices.
    ị⁸   Get the characters of s at these indices.
```

#### Sample run

```
JṡFṢị⁸  "abalone", 3

J       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].
 ṡ      [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
  F     [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]
   Ṣ    [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
    ị⁸  "abbaaalllooonne"
```

Comment: That split+flatten+sort method is pure genius. Nice! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n,i=1:s and s[0]*len(s[:i][:n])+f(s[1:],n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCoAgFEDRva8Qp8w3ZE0JfYk4WGYK9pJs6eut1mi8h5uu0@/YleLGaLbJGpIBIYxCZmLQkqxa3cQF66xk0EqiZtw9IaR@Py5YSUfAk7iammm2i1s9hZ5VX/1BCuJDFAZWbg)

Also 57:

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,n,i=1:s and s[0]*len(s[:i])+f(s[1:],n,i+(i<n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxDkAwFEDR3Vc0nfp4gzJp9EukQ6nShEfU4uuLVWw3J3e/znmjKiWvF7v2zrKIhEFLFZklx2JXmnwZScROBQOFf0Iq8z6FCC0BpP0IdDIvuO0HN/pp5lhD9tUf5Cg/xLGBdAM)

Comment: Can you explain your logic behind `len(s[:i][:n])`? I'm convinced there's a shorter way to get that number but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Never mind, I got it! But it's one byte shorter than `min(len(s),i,n)`. Great job!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [Chas Brown's shorter method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129704/69583) using `min()`.*

```js
s=>n=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c.repeat(Math.min(i+1,s.length-i,n)))
```

Takes input in currying syntax: `f("abalone")(3)`.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
s=>n=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c.repeat(Math.min(i+1,s.length-i,n)))
```

```html
<div oninput="O.value=f(S.value)(+N.value)">String: <input id=S> N: <input id=N size=3></div>Out: <input id=O size=50 disabled>
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
J««U$⁸x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r0OpDq0NVHjXuqPj//39iUmJOfl7qf2MA)

**How it Works**

```
J««U$⁸x - main link, input e.g. abalone
J        - range of length of letters: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
 «       - minimum of each term with second input: [1,2,3,3,3,3,3]
  «U$    - termwise minimum with the reverse: 
                    min([1,2,3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3,2,1])=[1,2,3,3,3,2,1]
     ⁸x  - repeat each character of the input a number of times corresponding to elements:
                    a*1;b*2;a*3...e*1 = abbaaalllooonne
```

*-1 byte thanks to @LeakyNun*

Comment: Good find @LeakyNun! The closest I got in that direction was `J«¥@«U$x@` for 9 bytes.

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: @fireflame241 genenrally, `x@⁸` is equivallent to `⁸x` (I used `⁸` here)

Answer (score 2):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

*Thanks to @Laikoni for helping to shave off 1 byte*

```hs
n#s=do(i,c)<-zip[1..]s;replicate(minimum[n,i,length s-i+1])c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsIwEAXvfsWSekhIW6getf5I6SGmwS4mm9LEiz8fidoK6sA7DcMbVbgaa1OiIrSD51hqcazuOHVNXffhMJvJolbRcIeE7uY6KrG0hi5x5EFUKJte6OQUErQweJhmpAhbYHsoQJ2V9WTgSXUCBlICz4a9FRMbWFnbXW4zi/lqM//L16selv28fhQT6QE)

Ungolfed:

```hs
(#) n string = do
    (i, char) <- zip [1..] string
    replicate (minimum [n, i, length(string)-i+1]) char
```

Comment: Great use of a `do` block! Save a byte by dropping the parenthesis in `length(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (Lambdabot), 74 bytes

```hs
r=replicate
f x n=join$zipWith r([1..n]++r(length x-2*n)n++reverse[1..n])x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsJADADQ3a8IpUNr8UCdOzl3dhCHqKmNpsmRHnL482fB9fEmXN4kUniO5glOpslNwmCKj@K9UxS@Y6LNCBm0fxlr/eV45jSBN5d9CHrtOm@E9LlS3h222uoq9CFf6B/aXGZkhR6isyaoYYQKbyimVMGx/AA)

Comment: Imports count in the score! You would be better of with `>>=id`

Comment: Yeah, I did that too before and then I saw [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92314/48198) (that's why there's Lambdabot in brackets). What is the right way?

Comment: I stand corrected, I think this is alright!

Comment: Good to know, there are a lot of very handy imports in that list.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 24 bytes

```
(<.&n<./(|.,:[)>:i.#s)#s
```

The bit in parens -- `(<.&n<./(|.,:[)>:i.#s)` -- creates the `1 2 ... n n n ... 2 1` array, as follows:

```
                   #s    length of s, call it L
                 i.      numbers 0 1 ... L-1
               >:        increment by 1, now 1 2 ... L
        (|.,:[)          fork: |. = reverse, ,: = stack, [ = identity
                         resulting in  L ... 2 1
                                       1 2 ... L 
     <./                 min of each element of the top and bottom row
 <.&n                    min of each resulting elm and n
```

once we have that, J's `#` operator automatically does exactly what asked for, duplicating each element the number of times specified.

Curious to see a J expert's improvment on this...

Comment: 23 bytes with a quite different approach `[#~#@[$([:>:<:,&:i.-)@]` (maybe a stray space got caught in there). I'm at a loss as to why the hook isn't taking `x` but not in too much a position to care.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ËpVm°TEnUÊ
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=y3BWbbBURW5Vyg==&input=ImFiYWxvbmUiCjM=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U` and integer `V`.

```
Ë
```

Map over `U` and replace every character.

```
Vm
```

Get the minimum of `V`, ...

```
°T
```

`T` (initially `0`) incremented by 1, ...

```
EnUÊ
```

And the index of the current character (`E`) subtracted from (`n`) the length (`Ê`) of `U`.

```
p
```

Repeat the current character that many times.

Implicitly output the final string.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 75 bytes

```php
for([,$a,$n]=$argv;--$z?:($x=$a[$i]).$z=min($n,strlen($a)-$i,++$i);)echo$x;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3066bc5793d82918b5c1eba515ea02e999d3f674)

## PHP>=7.1, 78 bytes

```php
for([,$a,$n]=$argv;~$x=$a[$i];)for($z=min($n,strlen($a)-$i,++$i);$z--;)echo$x;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dbe2b8f89106e0fecfa1f17adc9604792260f9a)

## PHP>=7.1, 80 bytes

```php
for([,$a,$n]=$argv;$i<$l=strlen($a);)echo str_repeat($a[$i],min($n,$l-$i,++$i));
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f862e2c131ce1d618f741b82cfa77e6d14ccb3b4)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 bytes

```r
function(N,s)paste(rep(strsplit(s,"")[[1]],c(1:N,rep(N,nchar(s)-2*N),N:1)),collapse="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEEDRu7iaiWlh7YSuMBeIFpMoBaLi2Pmtlp/HbyNuIz7Z97tkYFKsoj1ACxW0N63p7qBkDO67PQ7yYB3Tr0zZX9JAcV4mRmJnEcmXlKRq2L5jRFjJyCmp5PDlCw)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 68 bytes

```
f=lambda s,n:''.join(s[i]*min(i+1,len(s)-i,n)for i in range(len(s)))
```

Comment: You don't need the `f=` in the answer; the function can be anonymous. With that in mind, you can remove 3 bytes with `lambda s,n:''.join(c*min(i+1,len(s)-i,n)for i,c in enumerate(s))`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
₁₁ṀR
↔z↑N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1FTIxA93NkQxPWobUrVo7aJfv///zf@n5iUmJOflwoA)

The first line is the main function, it repeats each letter *n* times and then calls the second line twice.

The second line takes at most N letters from each group of repeated letters, where N is the 1-based index of the group, then reverses the list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 68 bytes

```hs
g 1
g _""_=""
g i(a:b)n=(a<$[1..min(length b+1)$min i n])++g(i+1)b n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYq9CoMwAIR3n@KIDhFRkG6lGaQUFylC6dQWyY/EYIyltVPps6dZukiHg@/uu4E/x95a/85jNNWxPlf1Afu2RZx/opFdvUYZaXSEdIyQQIbyrUgdo3yXXMqimIyjtnd6GSCyMk1Ch4G7pVmmqQmLgPMTDyuDmiPg/lpOy6NxSDCCcMHt7HqCzR8l1S8rH5yQUiqlOA@4YkXC138B)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
{⍵/⍨⍺⌊i⌊⌽i←⍳≢⍵}
```

`{`…`}` function where left argument (cap) is *⍺* and right argument (string) is *⍵*:

`≢⍵` count the number of characters in the string

`⍳` generate that many **ɩ**ntegers

`i←` store in *i*

`⌽` reverse

`i⌊` pairwise minimum with *i*

`⍺⌊` pairwise minimum with the cap

`⍵/⍨` use those numbers to replicate the letters of the string

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71b9R/1rnjUu@tRT1cmED/q2ZsJlHjUu/lR5yKgbO3//8YKaQrqiUlAXXmp6lxGYB4IqHNBZZJTYFgdAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), 96 bytes

```fs
let f(s:string)n=Seq.mapi(fun i c->System.String(c,Seq.min[i+1;s.Length-i;n]))s|>String.concat""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCsIwEIDhVzkOhARNQNws9gm6ZRSHGJN6YC/VOwfBd49ScfiHH74ibqpcW7tlhWJkL/ogHi0fQr77Kc5kypOBILk@vETz5MMiTNosgvhI620nfsg86tVRxydr5d3/mE@VU1TENn9XCwOuBMEUwHhOl38IO9s@)

A port of [Justin Mariners javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129703/20151)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>101</s> 97 bytes

```java
n->s->{int i=0,j;for(char c:s)for(j=s.length-i++,j=j<i?j:i,j=j<n?j:n;j-->0;)System.out.print(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5NawIxEIbv/orBU1LdIO3NuFuKUOihJ4/iIcZdTcxOQjIrLLK/fbsrFmpPpQPDfL0881p1UZkPJdrDuTd18JHADjvRkHGialCT8Sie5CQ0e2c0aKdSgk9lEK4TgPs2kaKhXLw5QD3c2IaiweN2ByoeE79JAT6Q3u/E1dpjauoyrvRJxe2uKKDKe8yKlBVXgwQmX8ytrHxkowD0MvFxsHkSrsQjnTIzm81tblfm1S7NrcOhQ2mzrFhIvmkTlbXwDYkweCGmuez60Ya8mamECsG17IULpXUZiE3VXjmP5VSQXw9P32JULeNc/kY5ZPwR8vwDMsY/EA8@9OE7/0zqJl3/BQ)

So much playing with indices...

Answer (score 0):

Abalone is a type of fish (well, a shellfish), therefore…

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 79 bytes

```
&i1\
0(?\:1+:&::&@)?$~i:@
&~}\&~1
0(?\:&::1+&@)?$~}}:
 ~r\
?!v>l?!;:o$1-:@
~~<^
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xy3TMIbLQMM@xspQ20rNykrNQdNepS7TyoFLra42Rq3OECIJlDHUhsjV1lpxKdQVxXDZK5bZ5dgrWlvlqxjqAjXU1dnE/f@fmJSYk5@X@l@3TMEYAA), or watch it at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

Reads the string from STDIN, and assumes the number is already on the stack.

Explanation: The second, fourth and sixth lines are the main loops. The details are some ugly stack manipulation, but in broad strokes, first, the second line fills the stack alternating between a character of input and **min**(*i*, *n*), where *n* is the length cap and *i* is the index of the character in the input: for "abalone", 3, the stack looks like

```
"a", 1, "b", 2, "a", 3, "l", 3, "o", 3, "n", 3, "e", 3, -1=EOF, 3
```

Next, line 4 goes through the stack in the same way in reverse, to get the right hand end capped properly:

```
"a", 1, "b", 2, "a", 3, "l", 3, "o", 3, "n", 2, "e", 1, -1
```

Then the sixth line takes each character–number pair and prints the character as many times as the number.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

Port of [xnor’s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129707/11261).

```ruby
F=->s,n,i=1{s[0]?s[0]*s[...i][...n].size+F[s[1..],n,i+1]:s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN63dbHXtinXydDJtDauLow1i7UGEVnG0np5eZiyIzIvVK86sStV2iy6ONtTTiwWp1TaMtSquhRixuaC0pFjBLVopMSkxJz8vVUnHOBYiA7MEAA)